# WPF QuickConverter: Hide element on empty list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `StackPanel` that holds a `TextBox` with a title and an `ItemsControl` with items. I'd like to hide the entire StackPanel if the list supplying the items is empty.
Instead of writing a dedicated Converter for the binding, I wanted to give QuickConverter (https://quickconverter.codeplex.com/) a try. QuickConverter allows to use inline C# expressions in bindings.

So this is my mark-up:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{qc:Binding '$P > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed', P={Binding Path=Value.Count}}"> <!-- this does not work. It's always shown, regardless of the element count -->
  <TextBlock Text="{qc:Binding '$P', P={Binding Path=Value.Count}}"></TextBlock> <!-- for debugging purposes only. It correctly shows the element count for the list -->
  <TextBlock Text="{qc:Binding '$P.Count', P={Binding Path=Value}}"></TextBlock> <!-- for debugging purposes only. It should do the same as the line above, but it does nothing -->

  ...

  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
    ...
  </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The first textblock is displaying the expected result, all other QuickConverter expressions fail to work. There are no errors or exception, neither at design time nor at runtime.

Thank you for any ideas.

Chris.

Comment: You can use **Triggers** if you want hide entire **StackPanel** without converter

Comment: I have used that in situations where I needed to hide the elements' container. But I wouldn't know how to address the container's parent. I hesitate to give it a name, since the StackPanel is itself inside the DataTemplate of an ItemsControl, so its name wouldn't be unique.

Comment: the ItemsControl  is not unique?

Comment: No. The portion of code I pasted above is itself contained inside another ItemsControl. It is in fact a nested list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have a `DataTrigger` in a `Style` like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: So simple. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Marked as answer because it got me the desired result. Although I'd still be interested in why my QuickConverter expression did not work.